# Filling an $8\times 8$ grid with the numbers $1$ to $64$ such that every $3\times 3$ subsquare has a sum less than $256$

Tags: matrices, combinatorial-designs

> Can you help me construct an $8 \times 8$ square filled with numbers from 1 to 64 (each cell has a different number obviously) such that every $3 \times 3$ subsquare has sum of numbers less than $256$?

I have tried to fill up the corners with the big numbers but I have failed to balance the $3 \times 3$ squares. I have also find some symmetries in the configuration but I still haven't succeed to stay lower than $256$.

The question is a subtask from a problem I invented myself. I don't post the whole problem because I want to protect my work and use it for future projects.

Comment: Looks like a job for a constraint programming solver.

Comment: I have solved the problem for 5x5 square and I am pretty sure that a consruction can be found for 8x8. Is not such a big square

Comment: @sirrah: Can you provide some context for this problem? If it's a textbook exercise, can you say what tools have been discussed for solving it? If it's an online challenge or something you invented yourself, what makes you believe there's actually a solution, or even a reasonable approach apart from applying brute force with a computer? Since comments are easily overlooked, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3589176/edit) to add any details.

Comment: @Peter: It would be naive to fill the numbers randomly. As sirrah says, the big numbers have to go in the corners, and the next biggest numbers on the edges (or near the corners). This is the only way to keep the average below $256$.

Comment: Nice idea. I have tried the same but I am not familiar with dp and so i failed.

Comment: A typical 3x3 square contains $9/64$ of your numbers; the sum of all your numbers is $\frac{64 \cdot 65}{2} = 2080$. That makes an "average" 9-element subset have sum $9/64$ of the total, i.e., $\frac{9}{64} 2080 = 292.5$. So from a (very rough) purely probabilistic point of view, it seems unlikely that you can arrange for what you want.

Comment: @JohnHughes but only $6^2=36$ such groups of 9 need be ensured sum < 256. The total number of subsets of 9 among 64 is far larger.

Comment: I have found a construction in 5x5 with sum of every 3x3 squares less than 93. With your thought this is again impossible (117>93)

Comment: @Mathreader: I understand that; I still have doubts. Sometimes a rough estimate like this can give one a sense of whether a task is feasible. Sirrah's 5x5 example shows that this isn't necessarily a sure thing, but ... well, it guides me to know how much time I might want to invest in trying to find an example.

Comment: Considering John's argument it is very unclear whether this can be done at all. Maybe genetic algorithms to approach to the minimum of the maximum of the 3x3-square-sums are suitable for this task in addition to some basic heuristics.

Comment: The problem statement would be improved if say explicitly you are only restricting *contiguous* 3x3 subsquares (to have sums less than 256).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One qualifying grid:
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
61 & 50 & 21 & 54 & 57 & 14 & 44 & 62 \\
\hline
43 & 32 & 12 & 36 & 39 & 19 & 31 & 49 \\
\hline
27 & 5 & 4 & 23 & 9 & 1 & 10 & 25 \\
\hline
58 & 40 & 22 & 38 & 56 & 7 & 41 & 52 \\
\hline
53 & 35 & 11 & 55 & 37 & 26 & 34 & 59 \\
\hline
13 & 20 & 3 & 15 & 18 & 2 & 17 & 16 \\
\hline
45 & 30 & 8 & 33 & 42 & 6 & 29 & 47 \\
\hline
63 & 48 & 24 & 51 & 60 & 28 & 46 & 64 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Sums of $3\times 3$ subsections:
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
255 & 237 & 255 & 252 & 224 & 255 \\
\hline
243 & 212 & 239 & 228 & 213 & 235 \\
\hline
255 & 233 & 255 & 252 & 221 & 255 \\
\hline
255 & 239 & 255 & 254 & 238 & 254 \\
\hline
218 & 210 & 222 & 234 & 211 & 236 \\
\hline
254 & 232 & 254 & 255 & 248 & 255 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: Amazing! I will cite your construction if I make a paper in the future. Thank you

Comment: I checked the enumeration $1,\ldots,64$ by inspection and the $36$ sums with a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

Assume we have solved the problem. Append column 6 as new column 9 to the right, then append row 6 as new row 9 below.
In the extended figure, we still have the sum property for all $3\times 3$  squares. We can tile the $9\times 9$ board with $9$ such squares and conclude that the sum of all fields plus the sum of all entries in the 6th column plus the sum of all entries in the 6th row, plus one more copy of field $(6,6)$, is at most $$\tag19\cdot 255=2295.$$
On the other hand, that sum is certainly at least $$\tag2(1+2+\cdots+64)+(1+2+\cdots+15)+1+1=2202.$$
This seems like it could still work.

However, instead of to the right/below, we could have extended to the left/up. 
The sum of 3rd column plus 6th column plus 3rd row plus 6th row ($32$ fields, of which $4$ are used twice) is at least 
$$(1+2+\cdots+32)+(1+2+3+4)=522.$$
Hence the heavier of the two rows plus the heavier of the two columns sums sums to at least $261$. Thus instead of $(2)$, we should compare to 
$$(1+2+\cdots+64)+261+1=2342 $$
and as this exceeds $(1)$, no solution exists.

In fact, from $\frac{2342}{9}>260$, we see that at least one $3\times 3$ square must have sum $\ge 261$.

Comment: Hi there. This is exactly what I did and found 255. But I think you are wrong in the point that you are finding 522 because you must add 1+2+3+....+28+1+2+3+4. This gives 255 that I have found.

Comment: I solved the problem for 5x5 with symmetric 3rd column and row for the record (a cross)

Comment: @sirrah: *"This is exactly what I did [...]"* ... You should include what you did as part of your question, so that people don't waste their time duplicating your effort.

Comment: You are right but I thought that this is another subtask of the problem.

Comment: For the record we can do the same technique for all the pairs of columns-rows and find a better approximation but still below 256

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen please edit your solution.